# cudaDeviceReset v. cudaFree

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda

There are various questions regarding the proper use of `cudaDeviceReset()`, but I haven't been able to find an answer to the following question.

The doc on `cudaDeviceReset()` says that it `explicitly destroys and cleans up all resources associated with the current device in the current process`.

Suppose I have a program with many arrays, all allocated with `cudaMalloc`.  Could I use `cudaDeviceReset` instead of many `cudaFree` statements at the end of my program to quickly free all the memory on the device?  Are there any disadvantages to doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `cudaDeviceReset()` at the end of your application if you choose.   In fact, this is [recommended](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#flush-profile-data) for proper usage of the visual profiler.

If you are in fact finished with the GPU and ready to exit your application, there should be no downside to using `cudaDeviceReset()` if you choose.  Note that probably neither of these methods (`cudaDeviceReset` vs. many `cudaFree` statements) are really necessary for this scenario since application exit will also free the resources (due to the destruction of the cuda context at application exit).  But note the statement above about profiler usage.